# What data type is returned from the numpy function

Tags: python, numpy

```
p = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(15, 2))
```

what is the type of data returned. I am trying to recreate this.

my list which im trying to replicate returns (ignore the values ofc) =

```
[[10,10],[10,22]]
```

How im appending >> mylst.append([int,int1])

Im trying to figure out how to return it with the same format so it allows me to make easy calls such as

```
print(p[:,0])
```

cant figure out the data type

Comment: `type(np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(15, 2)))` --> `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`

Comment: @SocketLearner1302 What happens when you try running `print(p[:,0])`? Are you getting an unexpected result? If so, then what is it that you do expect?

Comment: The [numpy documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randint.html) tells you exactly what is returned `int or ndarray of ints`

Comment: i expect for all of the values of index 0 to be printed within each list

Comment: How do i recreate this type?

Comment: @SocketLearner1302 What exactly do you mean by "recreate this type"?

Comment: You can try `p.dtype`

Comment: Indexing like `p[:,0]` only works numpy arrays, `np.ndarray` class.  `[x[0] for x in alist]` has to be used for a look-alike nested list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type is a numpy ndarray.

Here is how I got it:

```
print(type(np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(15, 2))))
```